# I am trying to define the following vector function, but keep getting an error

Tags: python, numpy, function, vector, ode

Where am I going wrong? The function:

[image]

The code I have written is as follows! Note the second def function is an attempt to integrate it using solve_ivp! please let me know if there are any issues there as well:

```
def fun(s, rho_0, rho_1):
return lambda t, s:np.dot(np.array([0.775416, 0,0, 0.308968]).reshape(2,2), s) + np.array([rho_0,rho_1]).reshape(2,1)

def fun2(t, rho_0, rho_1):
    res = solve_ivp(fun, [0, 5], y0 = [0, 0], t_eval=np.arange(0,5), args = (rho_0, rho_1), vectorized = True)
    return res.y[1]

fun2(t = 0, rho_0 = 0.0099532, rho_1 = 0.001699)
```

The error I get:

```
TypeError: fun() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Comment: you are giving a `t` argument to the function, but it needs also an `s` argument?

Comment: You defined `fun(t, rho_0, rho_1)` (3 parameters), but it gets called with `t, y, *args` and you provided 2 such arguments, for a total of 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html), `fun` should take `t` and `y` as it's first two arguments. Thus, you need to define `fun` as follows:

```
fun(t, y, rho1, rho2)
```

That's why you're facing this error, it is passing `t`, `y`, and then the arguments specified in `args` (you've provided 2 arguments, so you end up with 4 in total including `t` and `y`).

Comment: I have as per your suggestion rectified that issue, but now I am getting the following error from running the modified code: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'

Comment: @Carl  It's always good to try to read the error statement, often it's very helpful. After running the code myself, I can see the culprit is this line `return np.asarray(fun(t, y), dtype=dtype)`. Notice that `fun` returns a lambda *function*. It should be returning a float value: so rather than make it a lamba of `t` and `s`, simply return the value at `t` and `s (ie., remove the `lambda t, s:` and just return the dot product).